# <code>Replace a string with each line from another file

Tags: bash, sed

i have 2 files :
file1.txt

```
Monday XXXX
Tuesday XXXX
XXXX Wednesday
Thursday XXXX
```

XXXX is in every lines of file1.txt and i want to replace them with each line in file2.txt:

```
home
school
cinema
```

so output file is:

```
Monday home
Tuesday home
home Wednesday
Thursday home
Monday school
Tuesday school
school Wednesday
Thursday school
Monday cinema
Tuesday cinema
cinema Wednesday
Thursday cinema
```

I got the file2.txt has many lines so i can't do it by hand. So, i need a solution for it.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Is something as simple as:

```
while read i 
do
    sed s/XXXX/$i/ file1.txt
done < file2.txt > output
```

What you're looking for?

Comment: This would fail if file2 started with blanks or contained backslashes or globbing characters or any characters sed cares about like forward slashes or ..... A shell is an environment from which to call tools. The tool that comes with all UNIX installations to parse text files is awk.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|sed s/XXXX/&/g file1|e' file2
```

This uses the GNU specific `e` flag to run a sed command within a sed command.

or you can pipe the generated sed commands to shell:

```
sed 's|.*|sed s/XXXX/&/g file1|' file2 | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another one single awk command:

`awk 'BEGIN { while ((getline line < ARGV[1]) > 0) a[i++] = line; ARGV[1] = ""; } { for (i = 1; i in a; ++i) { t = a[i]; gsub(/XXXX/, $0, t); print t }; }' file1 file2`

Comment: The above will go into an infinite loop on getline failures where getline returns a negative value. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the tip. I remember seeing this requirement before, probably on the Gawk manual, or on a test situation. Just don't know how I forgot it and never even applied it on my scripts. The code above is updated accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, on output it can re-arrange the order of the lines from file1 courtesy of the `for (i in a)` construct. You'd need `for (i=1;i in a;i++)` or similar instead.

Comment: @EdMorton Nice way fo getting i in a without having an end point. I'll consider that on my next scripts thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{r=r $0 ORS;next} {t=r; gsub(/XXXX/,$0,t); printf "%s",t}' file1 file2
Monday home
Tuesday home
home Wednesday
Thursday home
Monday school
Tuesday school
school Wednesday
Thursday school
Monday cinema
Tuesday cinema
cinema Wednesday
Thursday cinema
```